# How to fix the position of LinearLayout item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I created a horizontal LinearLayout with 5 TextViews inside

Each TextView I set `android:layout_weight="1"`

The LinearLayout is `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

When I run the app, they are distributed equally

If I set a longer text to one of the TextView elemrnts  at runtime, another textview will change position

Can I fix all positions?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="20"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="20"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/change_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="changeValue"
        android:text="20" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="20"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="20"/>
</LinearLayout>



public void changeValue(View v){
    TextView tv=(TextView)v;
    tv.setText("zzzzzzzzzzzz");
}
```

Comment: can you paste your xml code?

Comment: can you paste your xml code here

Comment: Where's the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this,

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="first"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="first"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="first"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="first"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="first"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

am adding more text on some text fields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set below code instead layout_width :

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
```